# How to add modules to Play with Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

Coming from Ruby on Rails, I used to just do a `gem 'some_random_gem'` and then `bundle` in the terminal and there were my dependencies. Now that I'm bumping my head against scala and play, I'm discovering that it might not be that easy on this playground.

I'm trying to runa sample application and this is the warning/error:

```
module not found: com.wingnest.play2#play21-frames-titan-plugin_2.10;1.3-module-2.4.4
```

Assume I do not know anything. Assume I have no experience and no scala background. I do have some, but can you give me a description on how to solve this?

I'm believe you will need the `projects/build.scala` file, so here it is:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "play21-frames-titan-simple-app"
    val appVersion      = "1.2-module-2.3.2"
    val titanVersion    = "0.4.2"      

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        "com.wingnest.play2" % "play21-frames-titan-plugin_2.10" % "1.3-module-2.4.4",
        "com.thinkaurelius.titan" % "titan-cassandra" % {titanVersion},     
        javaCore
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      resolvers += "Oracle Releases" at "http://download.oracle.com/maven/"        
    )

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, there are two types of plugins.

**sbt plugins** are declared in `project/plugins.sbt` using `addSbtPlugin("organization" % "plugin-name" % "version")` -  the same way that Play is enabled (Play is nothing more than an sbt plugin).

You can find more info about it in the [sbt plugins documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Using-Plugins).

**Play plugins** are normal dependencies but must be activated in the `conf/play.plugins` file (create it if non-existent) using the `<priority>:<qualified-plugin-name>` syntax, e.g. `500:se.radley.plugin.salat.SalatPlugin`.

Unfortunately, this part of Play is not documented.

Comment: Thankyou for the information. Are you able to tell me how to solve this error or where I should be doing my reading?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the README? It seems you have to checkout the plugin and publish it to your local ivy repo. After that you should run `play update` on your project.

Comment: Looks like I need to do some reading on ivy repos.. Thanks for the info.